# How to import python file from different folder in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python-3.x

I can't import a python file from different folder in visual studio code. I also tried to save a **init**.py file in my module but got the same error.
I don't wanna use pythonPATH.

```
import my_module.shopping_cart
```

the error I get:

```
/python/sample codes/notebook.py", line 4, in <module>
import my_module.shopping_cart
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'

Comment: You could try to refer to [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: I checked that. that did not work

Comment: what I did is, I saved the module folder in the parent folder that contains my notebook.py file and I get another error:

Answer (score 1):

Give me an example. 
I just test in my machine with tree folder

```
C:.
├───child
├───---- child.py
├───parent
├───---- parent.py
```

In child.py

```
aaa = 1234
print aaa
```

In parent.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../child')
from child import aaa

print aaa
```

And result:

```
1234 # result from child.py
1234 # result from parent.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.

1. Include an extra path for your other folder. In VSC you can have in your settings.json file the variable "python.analysis.extraPaths" and include the folder you want
2. Install your module as a python custom module.
   You can see how to do it following this instructions
   https://docs.python.org/3.11/install/index.html.

Example file setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='custom_package',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        # List your dependencies here
    ],
    # Other package metadata...
)
```